# Continuous week transition over years

Tags: r, as.date

I'm trying to calculate week offset using `as.Date` with respect to any `origin` or base date. E.g.:

```
bd = as.Date("2013-12-29")
ad1 = as.Date("2014-01-01")
ad1w = as.numeric(strftime(ad1, format = "%W"))
ad2 = as.Date("2015-04-20")
ad2w = as.numeric(strftime(ad2, format = "%W"))
```

Gives: `ad1w = 0`, `ad2w = 16`. I would like `ad1w` and `ad2w` to be not 0 and 16 but a number with offset to `bd`. Is it possible? Origin can be any date. Thanks!

To clarify a little bit. Let's say:

```
bd = as.Date("2013-12-25")
ad1 = as.Date("2015-01-07")
ad2 = as.Date("2015-01-06")
```

I.e. `bd` is week 51 in 2013, and both `ad1` and `ad2` are week 1 in 2015. Both offsets should be 54 weeks, w/o rounding.

Comment: What you would like in the case above the `ad1w` and `ad2w` to be?

Comment: 0 and 52+16=68. Note - numbers must not be hardcoded, as `bd` can be arbitrary number of years/months away from `adX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this suffice?

```
ad1w <- as.numeric(floor((ad1 - bd) /7))
ad2w <- as.numeric(floor((ad2 - bd) /7))
```

***Update***

using `lubridate` you can use:

```
library(lubridate)

ad1w <- as.numeric(floor((ad1-lubridate::wday(ad1) - (bd-lubridate::wday(bd))) /7))
ad2w <- as.numeric(floor((ad2-lubridate::wday(ad2) - (bd-lubridate::wday(bd))) /7))
```

The logic is the following. Re code each date to be the last date of the previous week, and then use the `as.numeric(floor((recoded_ad1 - recoded_bd) /7))`

Comment: Thanks. That is an almost-working solution for me. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to do keeping `date` format. E.g. if dates were "2015-01-07" and "2015-01-06", `difftime(ad1,ad2,units=weeks) = 0.14`

Comment: Hmm.. This gives wrong result: `bd = as.Date("2013-12-28"); ad1 = as.Date("2015-01-07"); ad2 = as.Date("2015-01-06")` Results in `54 53` while it should be the same. I mean, mathematically it is right, but for the purposes of application - ad1 and ad2 week in this second example must be 53 both (as they both belong to week 1 in 2015)

Comment: Pls, see my edit to original question. With `floor` it gives different offsets for `bd` of 2015-01-28

Comment: Ok got it. I will post my answer in a few.

Comment: Saw your new post. Thanks!! I will test it on few cases, but it looks like the result is stable (I was interested in identical results for both) irrespective of `%U` or `%W`. Will Accept. Thank you for your help and patience with my test cases

Comment: One follow up question. What if I want to start week on Monday. I.e. `bd = 2013-12-22` will be week 50 of 2013. Hence will be looking for 55 weeks offset for bothy? (gives 54 now, as starts by default on Sunday?)

Comment: I am sorry , i am not following. The logic is that for all dates we recode them to be the last day of the previous day (we could have the first day of the week they are in) and do the subtractions then.

Comment: I mean if `bd` is on Sunday, say 2013-12-22, and `ad` is Monday 2013-12-23, the diff should be 1 week. Analogous to `%W` format

Comment: aaah ok, so you would like the week to start from Monday and not from Sunday. just add `(lubridate::wday(bd)==1)*1` and subtract `(lubridate::wday(ad1)==1)*1` to the final `ad1w`

Comment: Thank you! Works to my specs now. (I wonder if I can double up-vote an answer?)